# How to delete ElasticSearch snapshots by prefix

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-snapshot

I'm taking ES snapshots for every 15min, snapshot name will be in the format es-snapshot-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS

Two questions:

1. As per documentation it will be incremental, and I never attempted to delete any. But after 3months, now I couldn't able to query the list of snapshots (giving timeouts). Am I doing anything wrong in maintaining my ES snapshots?
2. If I'm OK to delete few older snapshots, Is there a way to delete by using a prefix like "es-snapshot-2019-06*"?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing anything wrong in maintaining my ES snapshots?

Probably not. From the Elasticsearch snapshot API [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html):

> Getting all snapshots in the repository can be costly on cloud-based repositories, both from a cost and performance perspective. If the only information required is the snapshot names/uuids in the repository and the indices in each snapshot, then the optional boolean parameter `verbose` can be set to false to execute a more performant and cost-effective retrieval of the snapshots in the repository. Note that setting `verbose` to false will omit all other information about the snapshot such as status information, the number of snapshotted shards, etc. The default value of the `verbose` parameter is true.

The documentation does suggest that you may experience timeouts as your snapshot repository grows. Running a `GET /_snapshot/<repo-name>/_all?verbose=false` should give you a successful response.

---

> Is there a way to delete by using a prefix like "es-snapshot-2019-06*"?

Yes, that syntax is supported. In terms of how that works with incremental snapshots, I don't have a reference for this in the docs but my understanding is that the incremental files from your `2019-06-*` snapshots would all get merged into your first `2019-07-01` snapshot, and this snapshot would effectively just be a bigger increment if that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the response. But I couldn't able to delete the snapshots using prefix and wildcard '*' at end. now we decided to use a different s3 bucket for snapshots.